# How to correctlycreate reusable useLocation function in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this code in my many components

```
    useLocation().pathname === `/${l.toLowerCase()}`;
```

Now I want to create a function and put this code in there so that I can only use that function in all the required components.

I created isPathMatching.jsx with following code.

```
    import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

    const isPathMatching = (language) => {
      return useLocation().pathname === `/${language.toLowerCase()}`;
    };

    export default { isPathMatching };
```

I think it should be work, but when I try to import in other components it gave me following error:
Attempted import error: 'isPathMatching' is not exported from '../../utils/isPathMatching'.
I checked, my imported path is correct.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Did you save the file where `isPathMatching` is exported from? How did you import it into the consuming component? I think you'll also have a react hook warning when you get the export/import straightened out. React hooks can only be called from functional components or custom hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed isPathMatching.jsx file in this way and it started works:

```
    export const isPathMatching = (useLocation, language) => {
      return useLocation.pathname === `/${language.toLowerCase()}`;
    };
```